# Make [cross-compile] a synonym of [cross-compiling]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[cross-compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-compile) and [cross-compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-compiling) have 19 questions tagged with both.

I do not see a difference.  I could retag all the *cross-compile* questions, but someone will just recreate it.  I could look though the questions and try to answer them to get five and then propose a synonym.  However, the user synonyms just sit there and when I force myself to answer a question like this, the answer is never very good as I have another motive.